# Newsletter HTML, div's and Outlook

Tags: html, css, mailchimp, newsletter

I work on a newletter with the MailChimp service.

You can integrate some code so I made a "table" with div's that I want one on the left and one on the right.

The problem is that in the micro-program in the service it works, but when I sent it in mail (the company got Outlook 2010) it puts the left div above and the right div under the first one.
Can someone help me please?

There's my code:

```html
 <div style="background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);width: 100%;margin-bottom: auto;overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="float: left;width: 50%;">
            <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Offerten</h1>
            <h2 style="h2 {font-weight: bold;}">Akustik / Lärm:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P16368: Anfrage des ASTRA für ein Detailprojekt Lärm (Einbau Schallschutzfenster) im Raum Lyssach
            
            <h2>Bauphysik:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P16360: Neubau Turnhalle Minergie-P zertifiziert und Erweiterung Schule Plänke in Biel
P16361: energetische und akustische Begleitung bei der Sanierung und Neubaus Mehrgene-rationenhaus in Zollikofen
P16364: Neubau Wohnüberbauung Lohngasse in Bellmund
            </p>
            <h2>Brandschutz:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P16251.BR: Das Verfahren für die Vergabe der Marktüberwachungstätigkeit von Brandmeldern wurde vom BBL gestoppt. Das Pflichtenheft wird überarbeiten und wir werden neu eingeladen einzugeben.
Voraussichtlich ab Mitte Oktober 2016
            </p>
            <h2>UVB:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P16335: Umbau Bhf Leissigen – Projekt der BLS
            </p>
            <h2>Beweissicherung:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P16343: Rissaufnahmen von 10 Gebäuden inkl. Erschütterungsüberwachung in Bellach
            </p>
            <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Projekte</h1>
            <h2>AS:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P16365: Durchführen von Sicherheitsaudits den für Wohnpark „Jardin du paradis“ in Biel (Implenia).
 
P14259: Wir wurden von der Baloise mit der Weiterführung der Logistik-Sicherheit-Verkehr-Entsendegesetz Beratung für das Projekt Baloise Park beauftragt. Dies ist ein Grossauftrag und dauert bis Mitte 2020.
Siehe dazu: https://www.baloisepark.ch/de/home.html
            </p>
            <h2>Bauphysik:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
            P16298: Neubau Data Center in Biel, akustische Beratung ab Ausschreibungsphase.
P16299: Umbau, Erweiterung und Neubau Schulanlage Rüegsauschachen. Bauphysikalische und akustische Beratung.

            </p>
            <h2>Brandschutz</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
Erarbeitung eines Workshops für Architekten zu Grundlagen im Brandschutz. Schwerpunkte: Entfluchtung, Brandabschnitte sowie Qualitätssicherungsmassnahmen gemäss VKF 2015. Voraussichtliche Durchführung bei Architekturbüros in Biel/Bienne ab Januar 2017
 
P16013: Ergänzung der Beratung bei Teilprojekten der Arealentwicklung Elsässerstrasse in Basel.
 
P16233 Erstellung eines EX -(Explosionsschutz) Gutachtens des neuen Forschungs- und Dienstleitungsgebäudes von sitem insel (Insel Spital, Bern).
            </p>
            <h2>Natürliche Lebensräume:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P1632: Unterstützung Umweltbericht MOB, Erster Auftrag in Biel in diesem Fachbereich!
            </p>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; float: right;width: 50%;}">
            <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Offres</h1>
            <h2>Sols:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P16351 : Expertise Sols-SDA Treycovagnes
P16352 : Suivi pédologique de chantier pour la réfection d’infrastructures agricoles à Valbroye
P16357 : Suivi pédologique de chantier pour la construction d’une nouvelle Landi à Cossonay
P16373 : Expertise Sols-SDA à Chamblon
P16375 : Expertise Sols-SDA à Pomy
            </p>
            
            <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Projets</h1>
            <h2>Sols:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P16351: Expertise Sols-SDA Treycovagnes
            </p>
            <h2>Bruit:</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">
P16366 : Bruit de chantier 24h/24 – STEP Lausanne
P16337 : Bruit de ventilation intérieure – HEIG-VD
P16339 : Bruit Routier – Valangin - Routes Cantonales
P15185 : Exposition publique Gabarit sonore éolien
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There's some screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: instead of using div , use table tag for your newsletter. and use `tds` in your code. like one `td` for left side content and another `td` for right side content, and give `width` to `td` according to your need.

Comment: You need to code likes it's 1995, only use tables to structure content. `divs` will break all over the place not just in Outlook. You need to test the template in every mail client (Outlook, Thunderbird, Windows Mail, Apple Mail etc.) and every major browser client (Hotmail, Yahoo, Gmail, Aol) in every major browser (Chrome, Firefox, all versions of IE) to be sure it won't break and display weirdly in one of them, as they all display HTML Emails slightly differently. Welcome to email templating hell.

Comment: This gives a good overview of the problems https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/

Comment: This is a decent boilerplate to get you started https://github.com/seanpowell/Email-Boilerplate

Comment: You have to use traditional approach like use only `table` and `inline-css`. some email engine will not render external CSS or third party library. for more guidelines you can visit here : https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Use align="left" or align="right" as opposed to float.
Float isn't supported in most email clients.

I would also suggest using pixels widths. Much more reliable than percentage widths.
Outlooks adds approximately 20px gap between tables sitting side by side. So keep that in mind if you need to use percentage widths. 
May require you bumping your percentages down, so 45% each.